# Why is Jordan Belfort using a dwarf instead of darts to aim at the dartboard?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In an office scene from *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), people are chanting numbers while Jordan Belfort grabs a
dwarf wearing a helmet, aiming at the bullseye of a large dollar sign
dartboard:

> Jordan: Twenty five grand to the first c*cksucker to nail a bullseye!

Then Jordan Belfort throws the dwarf towards the dartboard and the screen
freezes as his introduction begins.

Why is Jordan Belfort using a dwarf instead of darts to aim at the dartboard?

Comment: Because he's showing off how much money he has - that he can simply hire a dwarf (or dwarves - I can't remember if there's more than one) just to play darts with.

Comment: Without watching is again - I presume the movie is set in the 80s, when the 'sport' of [dwarf tossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf-tossing) became briefly popular/controversial.

Comment: Because it's very difficult to throw fully grown adults, and throwing children not only has a bad rep but they also cry a lot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately, this was an actual *thing* back in the 1980's when the movie was set particularly amongst such spoiled people such as the protagonist.

> Dwarf-tossing, also called midget-tossing, is a pub/bar attraction or activity in which people with dwarfism, wearing special padded clothing or Velcro costumes, are thrown onto mattresses or at Velcro-coated walls. Participants compete to throw the person with dwarfism the farthest. Dwarf-tossing was started in Australia as a form of pub entertainment in the early 1980s.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf-tossing)</sub>

Answer (score 14):

This actually happened, according to the [source novel by Jordan Belfort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(book)). They discuss the pros and cons of [dwarf-tossing](https://web.archive.org/web/20140824081755/http://twistededge.org/Funny_As_Hell/World_According/Midget_Throwing/) (**as a means of motivating their workforce**) at considerable length.

> It was less than five minutes later, and I was sitting in my office,
> behind a desk fit for a dictator, in a chair as big as a throne. I
> cocked my head to the side and said to the room’s two other occupants,
> “Now let me get this straight: You guys want to bring a midget in here
> and toss his little ass around the boardroom?”
>
> In unison, they nodded.
>
> Sitting across from me, in an overstuffed oxblood leather club chair,
> was none other than Danny Porush. At this particular moment he seemed
> to be suffering no ill effects from his latest fishcapade and was now
> trying to sell me on his latest brainstorm, which was: to pay a midget
> five grand to come into the boardroom and be tossed around by brokers,
> in what would certainly be the first Midget Tossing Competition in
> Long Island history. And as odd as the whole thing sounded, I couldn’t
> help but be somewhat intrigued.
>
> Danny shrugged his shoulders. “It’s not as crazy as it sounds. I mean,
> it’s not like we’re gonna toss the little bastard in any odd
> direction. The way I see it, we’d line up wrestling mats at the front
> of the boardroom and give the top-five brokers on the Madden deal two
> tosses each. We’d paint a bull’s-eye at one end of the mat and then
> put down some Velcro so the little bastard sticks. Then we pick a few
> of the hot sales assistants to hold up signs—like they’re judges at a
> diving competition. They can score based on throwing style, distance,
> degree of difficulty, all that sort of shit.”
>
> I shook my head in disbelief. “Where are you gonna find a midget on
> such short notice?” I looked over at Andy Greene, the room’s third
> occupant. “What’s your opinion on this matter? You’re the firm’s
> lawyer; you must have something to say…no?”
>
> “Well,” said Wigwam, “in terms of the insurance issues here, if we get
> a signed waiver from the midget, along with some sort of hold-harmless
> agreement, then I don’t think we have any liability if the midget were
> to break his neck. But we would need to take every precaution that a
> reasonable man would take, which is clearly the legal requirement in a
> situation like…”
>
> Jesus! I wasn’t looking for a fucking legal analysis of this whole
> midget-tossing business—**I just wanted to know if Wigwam thought it was
> good for broker morale!**
>
> [snip]
>
> **In essence, what it really boiled down to was that the right to pick up a midget and toss him around was just another currency due any mighty warrior, a spoil of war, so to speak. How else was a man to measure his success if not by playing out every one of his adolescent fantasies, regardless of how bizarre it might be?** There was definitely something to be said for that. If precocious success brought about questionable forms of behavior, then the prudent young man should enter each unseemly act into the debit column on his own moral balance sheet and then offset it at some future point with an act of kindness or generosity (a moral credit, so to speak), when he became older and wiser and more sedate.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Wolf of Wall Street by Jordan Belfort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(book))</sup></sub>